# Quando eu ganho um privilégio, posso perder ele se a reputação diminuir?

Tags: suporte, reputação, privilégios

Conforme evoluímos na rede, vamos ganhando privilégios de acordo com nossa reputação, minha dúvida é, se perdermos reputação (principalmente oferecendo recompensas), também perdemos o privilégio conquistado caso a reputação fique menor que o privilégio exige?

Comment: Se eu não estou em erro podes sim perder o privilégio.

Comment: @JorgeB. mesmo oferecendo recompensa? Em outras palavras, mesmo não agindo contra a plataforma?

Comment: Sim, se você chegar aos 5000 você passa a ter os privilegios desta reputação, se cair para 4999, você perde os privilégios concedidos a 5000.

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo, já fui conferir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Os privilégios são controlados pela reputação logo uma subtração pode remover ele.

Por exemplo ao chegar aos 125 pontos é possível dar downvotes. Caso o usuário aplique um em alguma resposta o saldo irá para 124 pontos o que não permite mais nenhum donwvote até a reputação subir novamente.